# Opposed of apoc.text.HexValue in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

are Neo4j apoc library have opposed of `apoc.text.hexValue`

that can get hexString and return value in hex number or decimal number ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is an APOC function that converts a string character into hex. But
there is no function to convert a string > 1 char into hex. https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/overview/apoc.text/apoc.text.hexCharAt/

```
apoc.text.hexCharAt(text :: STRING?, index :: INTEGER?)
```

For example: Convert the character "j" into hex. The 5th char (or index 4) of the string Neo4j is converted into hex

```
RETURN apoc.text.hexCharAt("Neo4j", 4) AS output;

Result: "006A"
```

Comment: There is function for convert hex number to Hexstring , and that is Apoc.text.HexValue 
but i need reverse of that ,  read that text from property and convert it to hex number ,

Answer (score 0):

You can create a GH issue for the inverse function.

Until then you can compute it manually too.

```
with "1FE" as hex 
return reduce(res=0, c in split(toUpper(hex),'') 
| res*16 + 
case c when 'F' then 15 when 'E' then 14 when 'D' then '13' when 'C' then 12 when 'B' then 11 when 'A' then 10 
else toInteger(c) end) 
as value, 0x1FE as comp
```

btw. Cypher also supports hex values: `return 0x1F`

Comment: thanks for your respond ,but my problem is , i have a huge db , it have node with property of type string , it`s hex decimal value but saved as text , i need to query like this :
MATCH (n:Node) WHERE n.Value < 0x100 RETURN n 
but it`s not working ....